# write IP + date to a text file + a line

Tags: shell, logging, ip

I dont understand how to structure a command that outputs my ip + date and a line break, something like this

```
wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo ; date >> ip_log
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe so with two lines:

```
wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain >> ip_log
date >> ip_log
```

Or so to open file once only:

```
{
   wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain
   date 
} >> ip_log
```

Hope it helps

Comment: definetly that helps, but i was wondering how to put it only into 1 line, passing the parameters from one command to another. 

Your way definetly works but it is opening the file to write 2 times. is it necessary ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is it: Logs the IP+date & uploads it to an ftp server

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date)
ip=$(wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain;echo)
printf "$ip AT $now \n" >> ip_log

### declare variables for the server
HOST='hostname.com'
USER="ftpuser"
PASSWD="ftppwd"
FILE="ip_log"
REMOTEPATH='/'

### upload it to server
ftp -p -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd $REMOTEPATH
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```